# ConstraintLayout view priority

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am horizontally aligning 3 views as see in this screenshot:
[image: horizontally aligned views in ConstraintLayout]

However `TextView` `(A)` could get very long and eventually overlap `(B)`. What I need to do is hide `(B)` if the happens. Is there a way to achieve this using `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: I would suggest doing that programmatically

Comment: At the moment I am, but ideally I am looking for a way to solve this using `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Can't see anything in ConstrainLayout that would suggest that functionality. What you should aim for is to set TextView(A) with a max width, that doesn't allow TextView(A) to overlap TextView(B). If you remove TextView(B), as you suggested , then that tells me TextView(B) is not mandatory and doesn't serve any purpose. I would argue to keep you deigns thigh and don't use any optional elements that adds a mess to the UX.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over how the UX is implemented and as such this is the requirement. It must be said though that it is not really optional, its just less important that what is shown to the left. Thanks for your help though.